# How to compare the value of an array element passed to a function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I am trying to write a function which gets input from the user in the following format: `0.3,0.2,1` in datatypes: `float,float,int`. If both floats have a value of 0.0 the data entry is finished. I initialise the three arrays

```
float col1Train[1000];
float col2Train[1000];
int col3Train[1000];
```

in the main function (it can reasonably be assumed that there are less than 1k data entries by the user), and call the function like this:

```
nTrainSets = readTrainingData(&col1Train, &col2Train, &col3Train);
```

Now, my problem is that the IF condition (marked below) crashes my program and I am not sure why. I want to check if the contained array element is zero..

Also, the alternative formulation of the same statement (at least I believed it to be the same?) Is not compiling citing a mismatch of float and *float - why is that / how can I fix that?

```
int readTrainingData(float *col1[], float *col2[], int *col3[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int scanfReturn = scanf("%f,%f,%d", &col1[i], &col2[i], &col3[i]);
    while (scanfReturn == 3) {
        printf ("read: %f, %f, %d", col1[i], col2[i], col3[i]); // Debug statement, execution succeeds
        if (*col1[i] == 0.0f && *col2[i] == 0.0f) {  // Causing the error
        //if (*(col1 + i) == 0.0f && *(col2 + i) == 0.0f) {  // Not even compiling
            col1[i] = NULL;
            col2[i] = NULL;
            col3[i] = NULL;
            break;
        }
        ++i;
        scanfReturn = scanf("%f,%f,%d", &col1[i], &col2[i], &col3[i]);
    }
    return i - 1;    
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: `*col1[i] == 0.0f` is not right. rewrite as `*(col1+i) == 0.0f` or simply as `col[i] == 0.0f`

Comment: @Fabulous I tried that as explained above, it results in: `error C2440: '==': cannot convert from 'float' to 'float *` during compilation

Comment: Why do you pass pointers to your arrays instead of the array? The function call does not match the function prototype: `float *col1[]` is an array of pointer, not a pointer to an array.

Comment: "it can reasonably be assumed that there are less than 1k data entries by the user" -- perhaps so, but it is easy enough to incorporate a check on `i` in the while loop to prevent out-of-bounds indices.

Comment: @mch , thank you! that solved it :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float col1Train[1000];
float col2Train[1000];
int col3Train[1000];
```

consider using a `struct` here:

```
struct train {
    float col1;
    float col2;
    int col3;
};

struct train Train[1000];
```

> it can reasonably be assumed that there are less than 1k data entries by the user

Never ever assume anything. Just pass the number of elements in the function call. So instead of

```
nTrainSets = readTrainingData(&col1Train, &col2Train, &col3Train);
```

use

```
nTrainSets = readTrainingData(1000, &col1Train, &col2Train, &col3Train);
```

Also, passing an array to a function effectively is passing a pointer to it's first argument to the function. So, call it like this:

```
nTrainSets = readTrainingData(1000, col1Train, col2Train, col3Train);
```

And then the function prototype needs a change too. Instead of

```
int readTrainingData(float *col1[], float *col2[], int *col3[])
```

either write

```
int readTrainingData(size_t size, float col1[], float col2[], int col3[])
```

or

```
int readTrainingData(size_t size, float * col1, float col2, int col3)
```

Which both are basicly the same. I prefer just the variant `float * col1` but one could argue, that `float col1[]` documents, that an actual array is expected and not only a pointer to a single value.

```
int scanfReturn = scanf("%lf,%lf,%d", &col1[i], &col2[i], &col3[i]);
```

Since `scanf` needs a pointer anyway, just calculate a pointer:

```
int scanfReturn = scanf("%lf,%lf,%d", col1 + i, col2 + i, col3 + i);
```

Now, in contrast to `printf`, where `"%f"` expects a `double` argument and `float`s being promoted to `double` due to type promotion rules (and `"%lf"` only having later been allowed to be used as synonym for `"%f"`), the `scanf`-family of functions actually have to distinguish between the two data types. So, to scan a `double`, you would use `"%lf"` but for a `float` (what you are using here) you must restrain to `"%f"` like so:

```
int scanfReturn = scanf("%f,%f,%d", col1 + i, col2 + i, col3 + i);
```

And then

```
    if (*(col1 + i) == 0.0f && *(col2 + i) == 0.0f) {
```

or (col1[i] == 0.0f && col2[i] == 0.0f) {

world work perfectly with the Cish way being:

```
    if (!col1[i] && !col2[i]) {
```

.

```
        col1[i] = NULL;
        col2[i] = NULL;
        col3[i] = NULL;
```

Here, please use `0` not `NULL`, because `NULL` might be a pointer and thus fail to assign to a non pointer variable.

```
        col1[i] = 0;
        col2[i] = 0;
        col3[i] = 0;
```

And finally to conclude the "never assume anything" part: In the `i` increment, test for buffer overflow:

```
    if (++i == size-1) {
        col1[i] = 0;
        col2[i] = 0;
        col3[i] = 0;
        break;
    }
```

Comment: How do you interpret »If both floats have a value of 0.0 the data entry is finished.«? Or are you referring so some other part of the post?

Comment: `%lf` requires `double*`. `float*` is not compatible. Also there is no reason to use clumsy pointer syntax in `*(col1 + i)`, when `col1[i]` will do.

Comment: oh, yea, may be, I didn't investigate `scanf` at all, I don't use it myself. Just edit my answer accordingly I'll accept it if it isn't accepted by being peer reviewed sooner. (Don't have time to do it myself right now.)

Comment: @replax please notice the edit to my answer regarding `"%lf"` and `scanf`

Answer (score 0):

The statement   `if (*col1[i] == 0.0f && *col2[i] == 0.0f)`  is wrong. The compiler will take the above condition to be a comparison between an array of pointers (*col[i]) and a float value (0.0f), and not the array you need to compare. The error

> mismatch between float* and float

occurs because you are comparing an address pointing to floating value (float* ) to a float value, i.e `*col[i] == 0.0f`

Rewrite the condition to `if (col1[i] == 0.0f && col2[i] == 0.0f)` or `if ( (*(col1+i)) == 0.0f && (*(col2+i)) == 0.0f)`

EDIT : As pointed out in the comments, you must change your function prototype as well for the `if` condition to work. instead of passing a pointer of arrays `float *col[i]`, pass the array `float col[i]` itself. Array to pointer conversion shall take place when the if condition is evaluated, thus making your code work as expected.